# Rearrange strings with regex from file

Tags: python, regex

So I have a file with strings that have a delimiter (`:`:)  I want to switch them around using regex but my attempts do not work

File contents:

```
foo:bar
foo:bar
foo:bar
```

My code:

```
combo = open("combo.txt", 'r')
outfile = open("checked.txt", 'w')
outfile.write(re.sub(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', r'\2-\1', combo.readlines()))
outfile.close
```

Expected output:

```
bar:foo
bar:foo
bar:foo
```

Comment: `\d+` matches digits. You could use for example `\w+` to match word characters

Comment: `(\w+):(\w+)`  and `\2:\1`.. try with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `string.split` method to get the desired result, there is no need to use regex. Use:

```
with open("combo.txt") as r, open("checked.txt", "w") as w:
    for line in r:
        tokens = line.strip().split(":")
        w.write(f"{tokens[1]}:{tokens[0]}\n")
```

If you want to use regex,

```
import re

with open("combo.txt") as r, open("checked.txt", "w") as w:
    for line in r:
        w.write(re.sub(r"(\w+):(\w+)", r"\g<2>:\g<1>\n", line.strip()))
```

After executing the above code, the contents of `checked` file should look like:

```
bar:foo
bar:foo
bar:foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid regex when there is no need for them.

This task is "split - reverse - join".

```
with open("combo.txt", 'r') as combo, open("checked.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(':'.join(reversed(line.split(':', 2))) for line in combo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex:  `(\w+):(\w+)` and replace with `\2:\1`

**Code:**

```
combo = open("combo.txt", 'r')
outfile = open("checked.txt", 'w')
outfile.write(re.sub(r'(\w+):(\w+)', r'\2:\1', combo.readlines()))
outfile.close
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtJ4RK/25) here

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do what was already suggested but I would loosen a bit the regex to also match on numbers and other characters until it finds the first `:`. Check here: https://regex101.com/r/kH6kHn/1